# Datastore RPCFailedError after porting an app to App Engine Flexible environment

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

I am attempting to port a Python app from App Engine Standard Environment to App Engine Flexible environment. Following [the directions in the App Engine documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/migrating-an-existing-app), I've changed my app.yaml file to use "python-compat" mode, as shown:

```
service: default
runtime: python-compat
api_version: 1
vm: true
threadsafe: true
instance_class: F2

inbound_services:
- warmup

builtins:
- remote_api: on

env_variables:
  GCLOUD_PROJECT: the-name-of-my-project
```

When deployed, any attempts to call into the datastore from the application (using the NDB api) results in the following trackback (truncated):

```
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/datastore/datastore_rpc.py" in check_rpc_success
  1371.       rpc.check_success()
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py" in check_success
  579.       self.__rpc.CheckSuccess()
File "/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/appengine/ext/vmruntime/vmstub.py" in _WaitImpl
  312.         raise self._ErrorException(*_DEFAULT_EXCEPTION)

Exception Type: RPCFailedError at /volume-list/
Exception Value: The remote RPC to the application server failed for call datastore_v3.RunQuery().
```

Any idea what the problem is? So far as I can tell, the App Engine documentation gives no special instruction for setting up NDB with the python-compat run-time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this bug this week, and after debugging it and working with App Engine support, found the answer.

See my [SO answer here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40198101/234270), or just add the following code to `appengine_config.py`:

```
try:
    import appengine.ext.vmruntime.vmstub as vmstub
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    if isinstance(vmstub.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, (int, long)):
        # Newer requests libraries do not accept integers as header values. 
        # Be sure to convert the header value before sending. 
        # See Support Case ID 11235929.
        vmstub.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT = bytes(vmstub.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT)
```

Comment: Works great now. Thank you!